# Remove rows if group contains an empty column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have multiple rows in my dataframe and a column called 'name'.

I want to groupby 'name' and remove every item in the group, if any row has an empty column (either, nan, none or an empty string).

How can I achieve this?

Input

```
       name    c0  c1  c2
193556   INFO    1       
273142    OMN    1  1   1
256278    OMN    1  1   1
41165    INFO    1  1   1
339649   INFO    1  1   1
```

Output

```
       name    c0  c1  c2
273142    OMN    1  1   1
256278    OMN    1  1   1
```

Comment: Can you add data asample?

Comment: just added, anything else let me know.

Comment: Please define "empty". Is this an empty string, `None`, `NaN`, or something else? You can test / check by looking at `type(df['c1'].iloc[0])` if the first item is empty in `c1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance don't use `groupby`, a better method is to get all names by the condition and filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

If the empty value is `NaN`, you need only change `== ''` to `.isnull()`.

```
names = df.loc[(df.iloc[:, 1:] == '').any(axis=1), 'name']
#alternative
#names = df.loc[(df.drop('names', axis=1) == '').any(axis=1), 'name']

df = df[~df['name'].isin(names)]
print (df)
       name  c0 c1 c2
273142  OMN   1  1  1
256278  OMN   1  1  1
```

**Detail**:

Check all values without first column by condition:

```
print ((df.iloc[:, 1:] == ''))
           c0     c1     c2
193556  False   True   True
273142  False  False  False
256278  False  False  False
41165   False  False  False
339649  False  False  False
```

Check if there is at least one `True` per column with `any`:

```
print ((df.iloc[:, 1:] == '').any(axis=1))
193556     True
273142    False
256278    False
41165     False
339649    False
dtype: bool
```

Get names by filtering column `name`:

```
print (df.loc[(df.iloc[:, 1:] == '').any(axis=1), 'name'])
193556    INFO
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter`, checking if an empty value (`""`) exists in a group and filtering on that condition:

```
import pandas as pd

df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: (x != "").all().all())
```